# Bounded quantification for Heyting Algebras

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Hey could somebody help me to prove the following law for Heyting valued models ( this is corollary 1.18 from Bells Boolean valued models and Independence proofs), which governs the assignment of Boolean truth values to formulas with restricted quantiﬁers.

Claim: For any B-formula $\phi(x)$ with one free variable $x$ and all $u \in V^H $,

$∥  \forall x  \in u \phi(x)  ∥ = \bigwedge (u(x) \to ∥\phi(x)∥) $

Thanks!

Comment: Bell proved a special case of your statement in his book *Intuitionistic set theory* with name "definite element lemma". However, he does not give any hint on more general theorem.